# Adding a charging lamp indicator to an alternator not having a connection for it

Tags: charging, alternator, lamp

I have this car alternator wired as follows:

[image]

So it's connections are: B+ output for charging the battery, one brush to the regulator sense wire (exciter), and the other brush to ground. **Is it possible to add a charging indicator with such setup?** I don't care if should be a regular light bulb, or just a LED with proper resistor (and diode?).

I asked this question to Poe AI and tells me to put a lamp between B+ and ground, but that's not correct because B+ is always hot, since it connects to the battery.

Comment: find a circuit diagram that includes a charging indicator

Comment: that's why i'm asking here...i can't find anything with an alternator brushes connected as this one: one brush to regulator and the other to ground.

Comment: Your alternator (as pictured) lacks external connections which would allow you to trivially add a charging light. Your options are to modify the alternator itself (I don’t recommend you do) or install some form of ammeter.

Comment: The alternator current does not accurately reflect whether the battery is charging. Only the battery cables do that. You may be able to connect a Hall Effect sensor to a battery cable to detect direction of current flow. The orientation of the sensor with the cable is critical. The A3144 might work, but I haven't tried it. I'm not sure the magnetic field from the cable would be sufficient to activate it. Also, it requires a 5V.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy ...or ammeter?

Comment: You will have to insert the ammeter into the circuit, but yes.

Comment: This is what AI said: Connect one terminal of the bulb to a switched power source, such as the ignition switch. This will provide power to the bulb when the vehicle is running. Connect the other terminal of the bulb to the excitation wire on the alternator. This will complete the circuit and allow the bulb to illuminate when the alternator is not charging or there is a charging issue.... However, then I'm concerned about frying the regulator by applying positive to its exciter output. Maybe it needs a diode to disallow that.

Comment: I work with neural networks and I have to say: don’t trust them with important things like expensive alternators, or high currents that can start vehicle fires, or rotating machinery that will snag your fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit diagram being referred to is that of a basic automotive alternator.

Here's a typical circuit of an older automotive alternator.

[image]

Initial excitation is provided by the battery through the 'charging indicator' bulb.

The 'charging indicator' bulb will be 'on' to start with and go 'off' when generation has commenced.

You may connect the bulb in series with the ignition switch and check for its functioning.

[image]